# Programa sem interrupção de sinal SIGINT

Tags: c, linux

Estou a tentar escrever um programa que se mantenha num ciclo infinito, e que não possa ser interrompido pelo sinal SIGINT(^C do teclado).

O que tenho até agora é o seguinte código:

```
void sigint();

int main()
{
    int pid;
    pid = fork();

    if(pid == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    }
    else
    {
        sleep(3);
        printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGINT\n\n");
        kill(pid,SIGINT);
    }
    void sigint()
    { while(1);}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma implementaçao bem simples de como capturar o SIGINT (ctrl+c) seria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void sigHandler(int sig)
{
    printf("SIGINT!\n");
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigHandler);

    while(1)
        usleep(100000);

    return 0;
}
```

Cada vez que voce pressionar o ctrl+c ira chamar a funcao `sigHandler`. A partir desse pequeno exemplo podes aplicar no seu contexto com quiseres.